# Why would Fred know that Dudley was on a diet?

Tags: harry-potter

Fred dropped the ton-tongue toffee in the Dursley's living room which Dudley ate and his tongue swelled. Mr. Weasley accused Fred that he dropped it on purpose because he knew Dudley was on a diet and he will eat it.

> "That wasn't funny Fred!" he shouted. "What on earth did you give that
> Muggle boy?"
>
> "I didn't give him anything," said Fred, with another evil grin. "I
> just dropped it... It was his fault he went and ate it, I never told
> him to."
>
> "You dropped it on purpose!" roared Mr. Weasley. "You knew he'd eat
> it, you knew he was on a diet -"

Is there any explanation to how Fred knew that Dudley was on a diet?

Comment: All the quote shows is that Arthur knew he was on a diet, and assumed Fred did too. Same question pretty much applies though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The preceding chapter confirms that Harry has been writing to his friends, including Ron, and had told them he was on a diet. Not absolutely explicit, but implied that he also explained why, and the whole family knows.

> The moment he had got wind of the fact that he was expected to survive the summer on carrot sticks, Harry had sent Hedwig to his friends with pleas for help, and they had risen to the occasion magnificently.
>
> Mrs Weasley, however, had sent the family owl, Errol, with an enormous fruitcake and assorted pasties.

Answer (score 22):

Harry seemed to be telling everybody that Dudley was on a diet. He mentions that it's "not going well" in his letter to Sirius, implying that Sirius was already aware of it:

> Dear Sirius,
>
> Thanks for your last letter. That bird was enormous; it could hardly get through
> my window. Things are the same as usual here. **Dudley's diet isn't going too well.**
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter Two - The Scar</sub>

He had also asked his other friends for food as soon as the new diet for the household had been put in place.

> But Aunt Petunia didn't know what was hidden under the loose floorboard
> upstairs. She had no idea that Harry was not following the diet at all. The moment
> he had got wind of the fact that he was expected to survive the summer on carrot
> sticks, Harry had sent Hedwig to his friends with pleas for help, and they had risen
> to the occasion magnificently. Hedwig had returned from Hermione's house with a
> large box stuffed full of sugar-free snacks. (Hermione's parents were dentists.)
> Hagrid, the Hogwarts gamekeeper, had obliged with a sack full of his own
> homemade rock cakes. (Harry hadn't touched these; he had had too much
> experience of Hagrid's cooking.) **Mrs. Weasley, however, had sent the family owl,
> Errol, with an enormous fruitcake and assorted meat pies.**
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter Three - The Invitation</sub>

Comment: Looks like that is one of the British/american translations. I guess "pasties" aren't too well known to leftpondians.

Comment: @JamesK In America, [pasties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasties) are little stickers that cover your nipples.

Comment: Huh... well, as an American I'm not familiar with the word "pasties" in any sense, but I probably would have figured out from the context that it's some sort of food. I definitely would not have guessed the stickers.

Comment: @JamesK - i thought it was a typo for Pastries but they are not Pot Pies (nor meat pies).

Comment: @Robert This is like how Brits chuckle whenever Americans mention "fanny packs"...